# Idempotency for BigQuery load jobs using Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

You are able to create a csv load job to load data from a csv file in Google Cloud Storage by using the BigQueryClient in Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 which has a CreateLoadJob method.

How can you guarantee idempotency with this API to ensure that say the network dropped before getting a response and you kicked off a retry you would not end up with the same data being loaded into BigQuery multiple times?

Example API usage

```
    private void LoadCsv(string sourceUri, string tableId, string timePartitionField)
    {
        var tableReference = new TableReference()
        {
            DatasetId = _dataSetId,
            ProjectId = _projectId,
            TableId = tableId
        };

        var options = new CreateLoadJobOptions
        {
            WriteDisposition = WriteDisposition.WriteAppend,
            CreateDisposition = CreateDisposition.CreateNever,
            SkipLeadingRows = 1,
            SourceFormat = FileFormat.Csv,
            TimePartitioning = new TimePartitioning
            {
                Type = _partitionByDayType,
                Field = timePartitionField
            }
        };

        BigQueryJob loadJob = _bigQueryClient.CreateLoadJob(sourceUri: sourceUri,
                                                            destination: tableReference,
                                                            schema: null,
                                                            options: options);

        loadJob.PollUntilCompletedAsync().Wait();
        if (loadJob.Status.Errors == null || !loadJob.Status.Errors.Any())
        {
            //Log success
            return;
        }
        //Log error
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two places you could end up losing the response:

- When creating the job to start with
- When polling for completion

The first one is relatively tricky to recover from without a job ID; you could list all the jobs in the project and try to find one that looks like the one you'd otherwise create.

However, the C# client library generates a job ID so that *it* can retry, or you can specify your own job ID via `CreateLoadJobOptions`.

The second failure time is much simpler: keep the returned `BigQueryJob` so you can  retry the polling if that fails. (You could store the job name so that you can recover even if your process dies while waiting for it to complete, for example.)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve idempotency by generating your own jobid based on e.g. file location you loaded and target table.

```
job_id = 'my_load_job_{}'.format(hashlib.md5(sourceUri+_projectId+_datasetId+tableId).hexdigest())
var options = new CreateLoadJobOptions
        {
            WriteDisposition = WriteDisposition.WriteAppend,
            CreateDisposition = CreateDisposition.CreateNever,
            SkipLeadingRows = 1,
            JobId = job_id, #add this
            SourceFormat = FileFormat.Csv,
            TimePartitioning = new TimePartitioning
            {
                Type = _partitionByDayType,
                Field = timePartitionField
            }
        };
```

In this case if you try reinsert the same job_id you got error.
You can also easily generate this job_id for check in case if pooling failed.

Comment: Of course - it's silly of me to forget that given that we *do* generate those job IDs...

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyMaloletkin, will give this as stab and report back on how this works for me.