# Bigquery Load in Cloud Function in Node JS getting Job ID without waiting

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm struggling with getting the BigQuery job id from my below cloud function code.
I need to job ID in order to verify if the job is done successfully

Here is my code:

```
 var storage = new Storage({projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID});
    var tableId = getTableID(file);

    const metadata = {
        sourceFormat: 'CSV',
        skipLeadingRows: 1,
        autodetect: false,
        writeDisposition: 'WRITE_APPEND',
        fieldDelimiter: process.env.DELIMITER,
        allowJaggedRows: 'TRUE'
    };

    console.log(`The file ${file.name} has been successfully picked up and going to be stored in table ${process.env.PROJECT_ID}:${process.env.DATASET_ID}.${tableId}.`);
    outboundHandler.sendStatusUpdate(file.name, process.env.IN_PROGRESS_CODE);
    var errorsState = false;

// Loads data from a Google Cloud Storage file into the table
   const [job] =   bigquery
        .dataset(process.env.DATASET_ID)
        .table(tableId)
        .load(storage.bucket(file.bucket).file(file.name), metadata);

          console.log(job.id);
```

Comment: Have you tried JSON.stringify(job) to see the full structure coming from the call? Also it's not clear which bq lib you are using

Comment: job is currently a Promise. I use require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to avoid using promise since I don't want to wait till the Big Query Job will be finished:

You can **set** your own jopId in the metadata object to monitor the Job status and avoid waiting to the promise response.

From BigQuery Load class documentation

> - @param {string} **[metadata.jobId]** Custom id for the underlying job.
> - @param {string} [metadata.jobPrefix] Prefix to apply to the underlying job id.

This is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50332552/1031958) to an example in c# of how to do this

However, Based on your description it sounds like you have an error which you are missing in your process.
I suggest you try to use `Async/Await` instead of `promise` where possible to simplifiy your code and help troubleshooting

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
// const projectId = "your-project-id";
// const filename = "/path/to/file.csv";
// const datasetId = "my_dataset";
// const tableId = "my_table";

// Creates a client
const bigquery = new BigQuery({projectId});

// Loads data from a local file into the table
const [job] = await bigquery
  .dataset(datasetId)
  .table(tableId)
  .load(filename);

console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);

// Check the job's status for errors
const errors = job.status.errors;
if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
  throw errors;
}
```

Comment: @Tmair Klein, Thank you , I added a custom job id and verify the big query job status externally outside of the CF (in a App engine service). As to use await I have limitation since I use NodeJS 6 (Node JS 8 is still in beta) . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to further use the Promise

```
const [job] =   bigquery
        .dataset(process.env.DATASET_ID)
        .table(tableId)
        .load(storage.bucket(file.bucket).file(file.name), metadata)
        .then(results => {
                const job = results[0];

                // load() waits for the job to finish
                console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);

                // Check the job's status for errors
                const errors = job.status.errors;
                if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
                    //console.log(errors);
                    callback(errors);
                    //throw errors;
                } else {
                    callback();
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                //console.error('ERROR:', err);
                callback(err);
            });
```

Make sure you call your `callback` on every possible finish.

Our function is defined as `exports.loadFileFromGCStoBigQuery = (data, callback) => {`

Comment: Thank you Pentium, This is exactly how I implement this before. However for 36 files that I load every day i only get a response for 75 % and the 25 % is not notify from BigQuery what is the status of the JOB. in another worlds BigQuery is not falling the response to the Promise

Comment: please see my response in an additional comment.

Comment: try adding the 2nd paramter the `callback` logic to your functions to pass errors/success further, we didn't setup anything else, and we get alerts when something fails and we run in 2 minutes around 1000 jobs, all work out ok.

Comment: thanks for answering, the only thing is that I want to get by pass async mechanism (callback,Promise) . I would like to fetch the JOB ID right away

Comment: how big is your files and how many files are in each run? we have a similar code that start to show some performance issues on GCP side. we have about 36 files that each of them about 1.5 GB